# Spring boot security adding 2 XSRF-TOKEN in response header cookies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf-token

I am using spring boot 2.2 security and below is my Java configuration :

```
 http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
.and().httpBasic()
.and().csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

I see in the response header, 2 set-cookie for XSRF-TOKEN as below. Not sure why.

set-cookie: **XSRF-TOKEN=**; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/hidden

set-cookie: **XSRF-TOKEN**=5564cfc1-884d-4b89-9bb9-11a92f42bcc7; Path=/hidden

What am I missing here? Relatively new to Spring security.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1

> Servers SHOULD NOT include more than one Set-Cookie header field in
> the same response with the same cookie-name. (See Section 5.3 for how
> user agents handle this case.)

It's indeed not RFC compliant.